# db4o on shared hosting with asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, database, hosting, web-hosting, db4o

I'm wanting to use DB4o on an asp.net MVC project i'm working on but wondering if anyone
has got this working on shared hosting plan, have contacted discountasp and asked them and they said go to the forum
as they were not sure if they supported it or not or any configuration that would be needed.

but the forum wont let my post on because its all filtered to only show comments they like the look of?

anyone had any joy with this with another host and one that runs asp.net MVC as it should be run?

much appreciated

ta

Comment: thanks for creating the tag mxmissile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the framework, but it seems that you can just place the DLL in the bin folder and you should be set. I've done tons of projects with MVC and the same method of placing the DLL in the bin folder and worked without issues. The host I use is [ReliableSite](http://www.reliablesite.net/v3/shared.asp)...they're cheap and don't charge $10/mo for a SQL Server database like DiscountASP does.

Comment: yeah thanks it was just the thing with it not running under medium trust for the way i have it as server/client  or client/server i forget what way round it is, anyway i contacted server interlect who seemed to have a bit less rudeness than discountasp and said they would work through any problems if i have them, thanks for the response.